# Magento sales order grid - add shipping and tax

Tags: sales, order-grid

So I wanted to change the columns in the sales - order - grid

I created my own version of the Grid.php (located at app\code\local\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Order\Grid.php)

in `_prepareCollection()` I added

```
$collection->getSelect()->join(
    'sales_flat_order',
    'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order.order_id',
    array(Shipping_column)
);
```

(not correct shipping column - this just an example)

and also added the column to `_prepareColumns()`

Logged in to Magento admin and I have a new column - no problem

Then I wanted to add the tax from `sales_flat_order`

Again I added in `_prepareCollection()` and `_prepareColumns()`

```
$collection->getSelect()->join(
    'sales_flat_order',
    'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order.order_id',
    array(tax_column)
);
```

Logged into Magento admin and page went crashing - never loaded and ended in temporary error (502) - both backend and frontend. Had to call support to restart.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field `order_id` does not exist in `sales_flat_order`. You need use `entity_id` instead of `order_id` and columns is working, it should be `shipping_amount` instead `Shipping_column` and `tax_amount` field to join query

so change to

```
join(
    'sales_flat_order', 
    'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order.entity_id ',
    array(shipping_amount,tax_amount)
);
```

Comment: So instead of listing 2 new lines with $collection-> etc just put in 1 and here I can list all the new columns from SALES_ORDER_FLAT I need?

Comment: just need one line